# Kali on USB not booting: [grub]

Tags: boot, kali-linux, grub, live-usb

I am trying to boot kali linux from Pendrive. SO I downloaded image for Kali live and then used rufus to write on USB stick. Then I disabled Safe boot (since I am in UEFI). when I boot into Kali (for the first time) I got: **a minimal terminal with grub**.

I looked on internet and found a lot of suggestion one of them being by [christitus](https://christitus.com/grub-rescue/)

I tried to follow it and when did `ls`, I got only `(hd0)`, `(hd1)` and another one which I don't remember but contains `/boot/grub/grub.conf`. I tried `ls` on `(hd0)` and `(hd1)` but did not work saying some error about filesystem.

so what to do now? how do I fix it?

Comment: Do other distros' live USB media boot? Kali is special-purpose enough that it can't care about the boot quirks on every possible laptop. Try a general-purpose distro with a different boot process, like the [fedora live image](https://fedoraproject.org/workstation/download/).

Answer (score 1):

This is [described in the Rufus Frequently Asked Questions](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#user-content-Using_an_UEFI_bootable_ISO_based_on_grub_all_I_get_is_the_grub_prompt).

> **Using an UEFI bootable ISO based on grub, all I get is the grub prompt**
>
> This can happen if the people who created the ISO chose not to add FAT32 module support in their GRUB EFI bootloader [... snip opinion piece...]
>
> In this case, as Rufus explicitly advises you to do if you find that copying files in ISO-mode doesn't work properly, you can try **recreating the USB and select DD-mode when prompted.**

Comment: But I ain't getting any DD mode or anything like that?

Comment: Did you create your Kali USB stick with a very old version of Rufus?

Comment: Nah it wasw the latest version

Answer (score 1):

This is is due to a [regression](https://bugs.kali.org/view.php?id=8441) that the Kali people will have fixed in the next release.

If you can't wait for the next release, you can download an ISO that includes the fix by going to https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-live and choosing "Weekly Image".

Otherwise, as @telcoM pointed out, you can just select *DD mode* in Rufus, which you will be prompted to select **as long as you do not create a persistent volume** (since it is not possible to add extra data to an image when *DD mode* is selected and therefore the use of persistence is incompatible with being able to let user choose between *ISO mode* and *DD mode*).

Comment: Oh so the dd prompt is not coming since I used all the space for perrsistanse storage